# Replacement for Security Manager checkMemberAccess()

Tags: java, securitymanager

The Java Security Manager method [`checkMemberAccess()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkMemberAccess(java.lang.Class,%20int)) had a parameter that contained the class that Reflection was being called on. This method was deprecated, with a description saying to use `checkPermission()` instead. There are no parameters in `checkPermission()` that are similar to those in `checkMemberAccess()`.

In a Security Manager, how do I get the Reflection target class without the [`checkMemberAccess()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkMemberAccess(java.lang.Class,%20int)) method?

i.e. if Class A performs reflection on Class B, I want to know that the *target* was Class B.

Answer (score 2):

When you install the default security manager - application then uses the default security policy. In case you want to provide our own policy, you can do it in a policy file written as:

```
grant {
   permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers.{class name}";
   permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

*CheckMemberAccess* have default policy - to allow access to PUBLIC members, as well as access to classes that have the same class loader as the caller. In all other cases, this method calls *checkPermission()* with the *RuntimePermission("accessDeclaredMembers")* permission

For reflective operations use a *ReflectPermission* class and *suppressAccessChecks* which allows suppressing the standard java access checks - for public, default (package) access, protected, and private members - performed by reflected objects at their point of use.

But this is dangerous in that information (*possibly confidential*) and methods normally unavailable would be accessible to malicious code.

Once you have provided the policy file - you can check it as follows:

```
 try {
   ReflectPermission permission = new ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks");
   permission.checkGuard(null);
   System.out.println("Permission granted");
 } catch (SecurityException e) {
   System.out.println("Permission denied");
 }
```

Comment: I want to allow reflection to all classes, but block reflection to a specific set of classes. Can I do this or do I need thousands of entries in that `grant` block?

Comment: There are  few other ways to block reflection operations: 1)`setAccessible()` 2) `RetentionPolicy` annotated class gets a RuntimeInvisible\ RuntimeVisible class attribute or won't appear in the decompiled class 3) Use `module` concept in Java 9 and  Reflection Permissions